# Laravel validation : Check Exist in two tables

Tags: php, laravel, validation, backend

I have the following validation, Where i am trying to check the email in two tables :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
[
    'email' => "exists:users,email|exists:user_company,company_email"
]);
```

But it only works for one table and that is the users table.

Is there anyway around it ?

Answer (score 2):

There is option to add custom validation rules in laravel. Read about this here [Laravel Custom Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)

For example:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => ["exists:users,email", function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    /* Custom Validation code */
                },],
        ]);
```

Comment: You should make Rule classes and use them like in the documentation. You can create 2 own rules and use them both, that way you can print out 2 different error messages if needed.

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    $data = ['email2' => $data['email']];

    $rules = [   
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'email2' => 'exists:user_company,company_email',
    ];

    $messages = [
        'email.unique' => 'This email is already exists in users table',
        'email2.exists' => 'This email is already exists in user_company table',
    ];

    return $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
}

$this->validator($request->all());
```

Comment: Don't do it this way, this is a horrible solution. Go with the other answer

Comment: This is intuitive.